# $Now.Year not working in Footer.ss file

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to include the year for the copyright info in my Footer.ss file for a Silverstripe project I'm working on. However, I can't understand why $Now.Year doesn't work. I can see the copyright symbol and the copyright text but not the year. Is there another way to get the year to show?

```
<div class="Footer-Text">
 $SiteConfig.Footerlinks
 <p> &copy; $Now.Year $SiteConfig.Copyright</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `<% control Top %>$Now.Year<% end_control %>` as the scope of `$Now` is within `Top`

Comment: $Now.Year works here. Check scope - are you on top or in a loop or a with? You can check it with $Top.Now.Year. Also inspect HTML-Source to make verify it's not a style issue.

Comment: I tried <% control Top %>$Now.Year<% end_control %> but that did not work. I replaced $Now.Year with $Top.Now.Year but saw nothing in the HTML source code--just an empty space.

Answer (score 2):

Have you got dev mode enabled? I wonder if an error is being suppressed here (possibly date.timezone PHP settings)

Edit: also, are you setting any variables when you include? e.g. <% include Footer Now=true %>

*I would comment instead of answer, but I don't have enough rep :(*

Comment: No, I have no variables when calling the footer include. It's just <% include Footer %>

I don't know if dev mode is enabled or not. I am new to Silverstripe so I don't know about this. I will have to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

$Now is global. It should work anywhere in spite of context/scope, be it include/email or not.

<% control %> should also never be used, ever (in 3.x - it's 2.4.x and lower code).

@kinglozzer is more than likely right. The short end of it is that $Now.Year *does* work.

http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-SS_Datetime.html#199-203

But (see return values):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

PHP's own date('Y-m-d H:i:s') will be emitting an error - which is just a warning (so execution continues) while returning false. You don't see this because your site will be in live mode. See the silverstripe docs for more info (again rep levels foil posting applicable links).

This means you have a server configuration issue, not a silverstripe issue.

Comment: I will have to look into this later...you're probably correct. Thanks!